# How to support unlimited parameters in extend function from lodash in typing of typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I using `extend` from lodash to "concat" the objects in the arguments like so:

```
import { extend } from 'lodash';

const foo1 = { item: 1 };
const foo2 = { item: 1 };
const foo3 = { item: 1 };
const foo4 = { item: 1 };
const foo5 = { item: 1 };
const foo6 = { item: 1 };

const b = extend(foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6);
```

The problem is after 5 parameters the type of `b` turn to `unknown`.

I mean when it just: `extend(foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5);` the type is correct.
But when it `extend(foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6);` turn to `unknown`.

How can I fix that to support unlimited parameters?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zhwvfk?file=index.ts)

- Please note, I don't want to use spread operator because `extend` not work exactly
  like spread operator. I passing to `extend` `Proxy` object which not handling so good with spread operator.

Comment: <pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what rest and spread syntax do.</pedantry>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp they say it's operator. anyway I can't use `...` to replace `extend`

Comment: One of many reasons not to use w3schools. Use a more reliable source like MDN instead. Or check the spec. It doesn't really matter much, but again, operators can't do rest and spread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the types for lodash, you'll see this for `extend`:

```typescript
interface LoDashStatic {
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TObject, TSource>(object: TObject, source: TSource): TObject & TSource;
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2;
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3;
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3, source4: TSource4): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4;
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TObject>(object: TObject): TObject;
    /**
     * @see _.extend
     */
    extend<TResult>(object: any, ...otherArgs: any[]): TResult;
}
```

Notice how there are explicit overloads for one, two, three, and four source parameters, but then a catch-all for more than that. If you want to support more than that, you could add to the types for lodash to do more overloads, but beware there's an upper limit. Here's what that would look like:

In a `*.d.ts` file:

```typescript
import "lodash"; // We need this import so that this isn't an ambient module, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49227

declare module 'lodash' {
    export interface LoDashStatic {
        /**
         * @see _.extend
         */
        extend<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4, TSource5>(
            object: TObject,
            source1: TSource1,
            source2: TSource2,
            source3: TSource3,
            source4: TSource4,
            source5: TSource5
        ): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4 & TSource5;
    }
}
```

*(Many thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for [helping me get that working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73090669).)*

That just adds a single overload for a fifth source parameter, but you can keep going if you like. There's some limit to overloads. I don't know what it is, but it's more than 20, so...

Note that the `import "lodash";` there doesn't have to specifically be `lodash`, it just has to be *any* `import` or `export`. This would work just as well:

```
export {};
```

It's just so TypeScript doesn't treat the file as an "ambient module."

---

Alternatively, you could always combine calls so you're staying within those explicit overloads for each individual call:

```
extend(foo1, extend(foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUwB42QOwCZwL5wBmUEIcARADYTYCGAzgBbkDcAsAFCcDGEm98PsjgBeRJziS4tAFxwAjJzzsOvfvBgB3CKPEcpcAEZyATEpVqBcGIyjJhYhBKnc5AZnM8+VwhACuULpO+lLYcgAsnqre8ITAAG4OegbIcgCsUZbw9MCoQc6ShHIAbFGcAPTlcADq0ADW9EbI3LR+9MLAMADkjYTImiiY-gDmjNJQw34gWDD0XupwdvR+lDDyumgYOAAUCHgANHBCh1oQJ7b2h74BAJQqlQYAegD8FVVSACoAnmAdjUiyOCYKaGZBQFj4OAAMkQRjkwJAoPBkJhSFcQJBYIhBFRcDCGMRWPwbzgADFaMBKI1tsRSNJrD9hL8oPRftwYAlkDdpI0vv4gRAMLhQS02sIbGDhLQ7NYIDoQLRMF95lYlisYCYNugsNhdgcjphkCdtOc7EaiP4oFdOXcSVIXnbJN9fnBgI0-Jg6kNNJhOCTalAGtJhhTfdEFmrVm4tVtdXtDpsddtjtYTdYLubrlaiDbbRwHvbXvn3k7Ga7-tJ4ZjkTjYcYCUjsdDYeiEY2UbD8W2ibWkKkGz3OEA)

Comment: yes this is work. thank you. but it is possible to do it in nice way? `extend(foo1, extend(foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6));`

Comment: or override the typing globally?

Comment: @JonSud - It should be possible to add declarations to the `_` namespace's `LoDashStatic` interface in a `*.d.ts` file to have those get picked up throughout your project. I'm struggling to get it working, though. I haven't done much with `.d.ts` files yet. :-|

Comment: @JonSud - I've figured out why I can't get it to work, but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is that the overloads in an interface are *ordered*, and the built-in catch-all definition `extend<TResult>(object: any, ...otherArgs: any[]): TResult;` is matched before my added definition with a fifth source object. (I've "proven" this by commenting-out the catch-all -- and my new definition gets picked up for the place I'm using it. But if I restore the catch-all, my new definition doesn't get picked up for the place I'm using it.) I'm afraid I don't have time to figure it out right now. :-|

Comment: @JonSud - FYI, I posted a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73090669/

Comment: @JonSud - I got a solution for it, so I've updated the answer.